# Mocking python function based on input arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

We have been using [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) for python for a while.

Now, we have a situation in which we want to mock a function

```
def foo(self, my_param):
    #do something here, assign something to my_result
    return my_result
```

Normally, the way to mock this would be (assuming foo being part of an object)

```
self.foo = MagicMock(return_value="mocked!")
```

Even, if i call foo() a couple of times i can use

```
self.foo = MagicMock(side_effect=["mocked once", "mocked twice!"])
```

Now, I am facing a situation in which I want to return a fixed value when the input parameter has a particular value. So if let's say "my_param" is equal to "something" then I want to return "my_cool_mock"

This seems to be available on [mockito for python](http://code.google.com/p/mockito-python/)

```
when(dummy).foo("something").thenReturn("my_cool_mock")
```

I have been searching on how to achieve the same with Mock with no success?

Any ideas?

Comment: May be this answer will help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7665754/234606

Comment: @naiquevin This perfectly solves the problem mate, thanks!

Comment: If your project uses pytest, for such a purpose you may want to leverage [`monkeypatch`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html). Monkeypatch is more for "replace this function for sake of testing," whereas Mock is what you use when you also want to check the `mock_calls` or make assertions about what it was called with and so on. There is a place for both, and I often use both at different times in a given test file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Mock object with method called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665682/python-mock-object-with-method-called-multiple-times)

Answer (score 331, accepted):

> If `side_effect_func` is a function then whatever that function returns is
> what calls to the mock return. The `side_effect_func` function is called with
> the same arguments as the mock. This allows you to vary the return
> value of the call dynamically, based on the input:
>
> ```
> >>> def side_effect_func(value):
> ...     return value + 1
> ...
> >>> m = MagicMock(side_effect=side_effect_func)
> >>> m(1)
> 2
> >>> m(2)
> 3
> >>> m.mock_calls
> [call(1), call(2)]
> ```

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#calling

Comment: Just to make the answer easier, could you rename the side_effect function to something else? (i know, i know, it is pretty simple, but improves readability the fact that function name and param name are different :)

Comment: @JuanAntonioGomezMoriano I could, but in this case I'm just directly quoting the documentation, so I'm a bit loathe to edit the quote if it's not specifically broken.

Comment: and just to be pedantic all these years later, but `side effect` is the accurate term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)

Comment: @Ish they're not complaining about the name of `CallableMixin.side_effect`, but that the separate function defined in the example has the same name.

Answer (score 108):

As indicated at [Python Mock object with method called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665682/python-mock-object-with-method-called-multiple-times/7665754#7665754)

A solution is to write my own side_effect

```
def my_side_effect(*args, **kwargs):
    if args[0] == 42:
        return "Called with 42"
    elif args[0] == 43:
        return "Called with 43"
    elif kwargs['foo'] == 7:
        return "Foo is seven"

mockobj.mockmethod.side_effect = my_side_effect
```

That does the trick

Comment: This made it clearer for me than the selected answer, so thank you for answering your own question :)

Answer (score 30):

Side effect takes a function (which can also be a **lambda function**), so for simple cases you may use:

```
m = MagicMock(side_effect=(lambda x: x+1))
```

Answer (score 22):

If you *"want to return a fixed value when the input parameter has a particular value"*, maybe you don't even need a mock and could use a `dict` along with its `get` method:

```py
foo = {'input1': 'value1', 'input2': 'value2'}.get

foo('input1')  # value1
foo('input2')  # value2
```

This works well when your fake's output is a *mapping* of input. When it's a *function* of input I'd suggest using `side_effect` as per **Amber**'s answer.

You can also use a combination of both if you want to preserve `Mock`'s capabilities (`assert_called_once`, `call_count` etc):

```py
self.mock.side_effect = {'input1': 'value1', 'input2': 'value2'}.get
```

Comment: This is very clever.

Comment: How would this look with multiple parameters? I tried it with tuples, as dict keys, but that didn't end well.

Answer (score 10):

I've ended up here looking for "*how to mock a function based on input arguments*" and I finally solved this creating a simple aux function:

```py
def mock_responses(responses, default_response=None):
  return lambda input: responses[input] if input in responses else default_response
```

Now:

```py
my_mock.foo.side_effect = mock_responses(
  {
    'x': 42, 
    'y': [1,2,3]
  })
my_mock.goo.side_effect = mock_responses(
  {
    'hello': 'world'
  }, 
  default_response='hi')
...

my_mock.foo('x') # => 42
my_mock.foo('y') # => [1,2,3]
my_mock.foo('unknown') # => None

my_mock.goo('hello') # => 'world'
my_mock.goo('ey') # => 'hi'
```

Hope this will help someone!

Answer (score 9):

Although `side_effect` can achieve the goal, it is not so convenient to setup `side_effect` function for each test case.

I write a lightweight [Mock](https://github.com/pilagod/nextmock) (which is called NextMock) to enhance the built-in mock to address this problem, here is a simple example:

```py
from nextmock import Mock

m = Mock()

m.with_args(1, 2, 3).returns(123)

assert m(1, 2, 3) == 123
assert m(3, 2, 1) != 123
```

It also supports argument matcher:

```py
from nextmock import Arg, Mock

m = Mock()

m.with_args(1, 2, Arg.Any).returns(123)

assert m(1, 2, 1) == 123
assert m(1, 2, "123") == 123
```

Hope this package could make testing more pleasant. Feel free to give any feedback.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `partial` from `functools` if you want to use a function that takes parameters but the function you are mocking does not. E.g. like this:

```py
def mock_year(year):
    return datetime.datetime(year, 11, 28, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

```py
@patch('django.utils.timezone.now', side_effect=partial(mock_year, year=2020))
```

This will return a callable that doesn't accept parameters (like Django's timezone.now()), but my mock_year function does.

Comment: Thanks for this elegant solution. I like to add that if your original function has additional parameters, they need to be called with keywords in you production code or this approach won't work. You get the error: `got multiple values for argument`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to show another way of doing it:

```
def mock_isdir(path):
    return path in ['/var/log', '/var/log/apache2', '/var/log/tomcat']

with mock.patch('os.path.isdir') as os_path_isdir:
    os_path_isdir.side_effect = mock_isdir
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `@mock.patch.object`:

Let's say a module `my_module.py` uses `pandas` to read from a database and we would like to test this module by mocking `pd.read_sql_table` method (which takes `table_name` as argument).

What you can do is to create (inside your test) a `db_mock` method that returns different objects depending on the argument provided:

```
def db_mock(**kwargs):
    if kwargs['table_name'] == 'table_1':
        # return some DataFrame
    elif kwargs['table_name'] == 'table_2':
        # return some other DataFrame
```

In your test function you then do:

```
import my_module as my_module_imported

@mock.patch.object(my_module_imported.pd, "read_sql_table", new_callable=lambda: db_mock)
def test_my_module(mock_read_sql_table):
    # You can now test any methods from `my_module`, e.g. `foo` and any call this 
    # method does to `read_sql_table` will be mocked by `db_mock`, e.g.
    ret = my_module_imported.foo(table_name='table_1')
    # `ret` is some DataFrame returned by `db_mock`
```