# Mocking Python function according to different input arguments unittest python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, magicmock

I have a utility function that takes the argument **case** and return the value accordingly

```
helper.py
def get_sport_associated_value(dictionary, category, case):
    if case == 'type':
        return "soccer"
    else: 
        return 1 #if case = 'id'
```

I have a main function that use the above function

```
crud_operations.py
def get_data(category):
    dictionary ={.....}
    id =  get_sport_associated_value(dictionary, category, 'id')
    .....
    .....
    type = get_sport_associated_value(dictionary, category, 'type')
    ....
    return "successful"
```

Now I am unittesting the **get_data()** module using the unittest.Mock. I am having trouble passing the values to **id and type**.

```
@mock.patch('helper.get_sport_associated_value')
def test_get_data(self, mock_sport):
    with app.app_context():
        mock_sport.side_effect = self.side_effect
        mock_sport.get_sport_associated_value("id")
        mock_sport.get_sport_associated_value("type")
        result = get_queries("Soccer")
        asserEquals(result, "successful")

 def side_effect(*args, **kwargs):
     if args[0] == "type":
         print("Soccer")
         return "Soccer"
     elif args[0] == "id":
         print("1")
         return 1
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162015/mocking-python-function-based-on-input-arguments) using **side_effect function** and facing problem to mock the **get_sport_associated_value()** according to the different values of input argument.

Question 2 : Which is the best method to use **mock** or **mock.magicmock** in this scenario?

Any help is appreciated with unit testing
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incorrectly testing `args[0]` as a `case`. The arguments of the `side_effect` callback function should be the same as the function you want to mock:

```
def side_effect(dictionary, category, case):
    if case == "type":
        return "Soccer"
    elif case == "id":
        return 1
```

Comment: !! It worked.
It would be helpful if you can answer Question 2.
Thanks