# How to return multiple values when using mock patch.object with contextlib.nested

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

I am new to unit testing and I am trying to write unit test using patch.object to mock the function calls. The mocked function `getObj()` is called twice in the function which I am testing. First time when its called I am expecting `None` as `return_value` and second time I am expecting `some_string`. I am not getting how to do it.

The code is as follows:

```
def test_create(self):
    with contextlib.nested(
        patch.object(agent, 'try_connect',
        patch.object(util, 'get_obj', return_value = None),
        ) as (mock_try_connect, mock_get_obj):
        proxy_info = self.util.create(data)
```

I tried using `side_effects`, and give it as input to `return_value` but every time its returning `None`.

```
mock_value=Mock()
mock_value.side_effect = [None, 'some_string']
patch.object(util, 'get_obj', return_value = mock_value())
```

Comment: Why are you using a set as the `side_effect`? Surely you want something *ordered*? Could you expand on *"not working correctly"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The `side_effect` solution I founded out from some other answer here. Not working properly means, everytime when the call is made to `get_obj` its return value is `None'.

Comment: Then edit the question to say that. You probably want a list, not a set. And which *"other answer"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe its not working with list too. The other answer which I referred is from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897145/python-mock-multiple-return-values?rq=1]

Answer (score 0):

Use `assert_has_calls` to verify the mocked out object is being called exactly how you expect it to be called. This will help you debug your issue.

```
def test_create(self):
    with contextlib.nested(
            patch.object(agent, 'try_connect',
            patch.object(util, 'get_obj', side_effect = [None, 'some_string']),
            ) as (mock_try_connect, mock_get_obj):
        proxy_info = self.util.create(data)
        mock_try_connect.assert_has_calls([mock.call(#params), ...])
        mock_get_obj.assert_has_calls([...])
```

Now once you've debugged the issue you can delete the last two statements since they add nothing to your test coverage and make your code harder to maintain.