# How to mock a function to get a different return value in golang

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I'm writing unit tests for a function that I developed in golang. Here is the code snippet:

```
func myFunc () {
    //there is some code
    err := json.Unmarshal (a, &b)
    if err != nil {
        //handle error    
    }

    //there is some more code

    err := json.Unmarshal (c, &d)
    if err != nil {
        //handle error    
    }
}
```

Now I want to mock first unmarshal to return success and second unmarshal to return failure. In python, I see one similar post:
[Python mock multiple return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897145/python-mock-multiple-return-values)

But I cannot find one for golang. Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not that simple in Golang. The best bet would be to refactor your function so that `json.Unmarshal` can be forcefully made to return an error, e.g. when calling `json.Unmarshal(a, &b)` and a is not in json format.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do in this situation is have an exported package variable `Unmarshaller` and set it to `json.Unmarshal` in the `init()` method.

```
var Unmarshaller func(data []byte, v interface{}) error;

func init() {
    Unmarshaller = json.Unmarshal
}
```

Then, when you want to force an error, you can just do

```
mypackage.Unmarshaller = func(data[] byte, v interface{}) error {
    return errors.New("It broke!")
}
```

Then, in your code, instead of calling `json.Unmarshal` directly, you call your package level `Unmarshaller, so

```
err =: json.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, &test)
```

would become

```
err =: Unmarshaller(jsonBytes, &test)
```

As a short example: https://play.golang.org/p/CinLmprtp5