# How to patch multiple inputs in python unit test using with statement - no decorators

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm asking this question having viewed these 2 similar ones:

[How to patch multiple repeated inputs in python unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223663/how-to-patch-multiple-repeated-inputs-in-python-unit-test)

[Python mock multiple return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897145/python-mock-multiple-return-values)

But neither satisfactorily gives me the answer I'm looking for.

I need to be able to patch multiple calls to `input()` using the with statement rather than a decorator.

The reason for this is that the test I'm writing doesn't allow me to use a decorator, nor modify the signature of the test method to add the mocked input as in:

```
@mock.patch('builtins.input')
def test_myMethod(self, mocked_input):
    mock_args = ['20', 100]
    mocked_input.side_effect = mock_args
    res = mymethod()
    self.assertEqual(res, 120)
```

My question is how can I achieve the same effect using as with statement as in:

```
def test_myMethod(self):
    with mock.patch('builtins.input', ...)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `as...` in order to get the mock instance as it is created by the `with` statement:

```
def test_myMethod(self):
    mock_args = ['20', 100]
    with mock.patch('builtins.input') as mocked_input:
        mocked_input.side_effect = mock_args
        res = mymethod()
    self.assertEqual(res, 120)
```

Alternatively, you can pass in the side effect directly to the `patch` call:

```
def test_myMethod(self):
    mock_args = ['20', 100]
    with mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=mock_args):
        res = mymethod()
    self.assertEqual(res, 120)
```

As you can see, doing this in particular case means that you won't even need a reference to the mock instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is just what I was looking for.