# Is there a way to use side_effect to simulate request responses?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I want to use side_effect as an iterator like specified in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897145/python-mock-multiple-return-values/69154988#69154988)

However I want to simulate responses, and when I try to access response.status_code in my function, I get the error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'`

How could I use side_effect to simulate different responses for the get request E.G.

```
mock_method.side_effect = [{"status_code": 404}, {"status_code": 200}]
```

I also tried to do so like this

```
mock_method.side_effect.status_code = [404, 200]
```

Which raised a similar error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

Please send help I  have a migraine and want to be done with unit tests yesterday

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty simple to solve actually, I just made a MockResponse class and set side_effect to an array of those objects.

```
class MockResponse:
    def __init__(self, status_code, content):
        self.status_code = status_code
        self.content = content
    def json(self):
        return self.content

mock_method.side_effect = [MockResponse(200, data="success"), 
                           MockResponse(404, data="not found")]
```