# Is there a way to test methods with a lot of raw_input in django?

Tags: python, django

I have found this URL here: [python mocking raw input in unittests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046717/python-mocking-raw-input-in-unittests)

and it answers my question somewhat, but what about the case when there is a lot of raw_inputs? something like this...

```
class MyModel()
    def my_method(self):
        raw_input("do you want to play a game?: ")
        ...do something
        raw_input("Do you want to do something else?: ")
        ...do something
```

Comment: If your class is supposed to be a "model" (in the MVC meaning) then it should NOT have anything like `raw_input()` calls...

Comment: its more like backend methods for managing classes

Comment: Even then it has nothing to do in a model class... Use a distinct class (or set of classes) to handle UI (if it's a Django project then custom management commands come to mind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: wraps each call to `raw_input()` in distinct object that you can easily mock.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you wanted to mock each and every `raw_input` method but set different return value. `unittest.mock` comes up with `side_effect` properties. that can be helpful in this case.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide

[Python Mock object with method called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665682/python-mock-object-with-method-called-multiple-times)

The key point here is the paramater of the `raw_input` function.

Example:

```
from unittest import mock
from unittest import TestCase

class MyTest(TestCase):
    @mock.patch.object(__builtins__, 'raw_input')
    def test_my_method(self, mock_input):
        # If raw_input called thrice in the my_method
        mock_input.side_effect = lambda param: {'First': 'Great', 'Second': 'Good', 'Third':
'Awesome'}.get(param, 'Default return')
        my_class = actual_module.MyModel()
        self.assertEqual(my_class.my_method(), 'GreatGoodAwesome')
```

Here 'First', 'Second' 'Third' are the actual string of the raw_input used in the method.
So the only thing you need to modify is to replace the 'First' with 'do you want to play a game?: ' and so on.

And Assuming `my_method` returns the concatenation of the response of the raw_input method.
Please note that code is not properly tested.

Comment: i've been reading over those docs and I think that will do the trick for me but I am unsure about how to actually execute it in my example, could you write a simple example if you have time?