# pytest monkeypatch: it is possible to return different values each time when patched method called?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

In `unittest` I can assert to [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=side_effect#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) iterable with values - each of them one-by-one will be returned when patched method called, moreover I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7665754/1879101) that in `unittest` my patched method can return different results according to input arguments. Can I make something like that in pytest? [Documentation](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html#example-preventing-requests-from-remote-operations) does not mention this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly monkeypatch something with a class with a `__call__` attribute which does whatever you want - however, nothing keeps you from using `unittest.mock` with pytest - there's even the [`pytest-mock` plugin](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock/) to make this easier.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Mock's [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) parameter to set what is to be returned for each call.

> side_effect: A function to be called whenever the Mock is called. See the side_effect attribute. Useful for raising exceptions or dynamically changing return values. The function is called with the same arguments as the mock, and unless it returns DEFAULT, the return value of this function is used as the return value.
> Alternatively side_effect can be an exception class or instance. In this case the exception will be raised when the mock is called.
> If side_effect is an iterable then each call to the mock will return the next value from the iterable.
> A side_effect can be cleared by setting it to None.

For instance:

```
return_data = [3, 5]
test_mock = Mock(side_effect=return_data)
monkeypatch.setattr(your_module, "some_func", test_mock)
```

This way first time your call calls "some_func" it will return 3 and when you call it a second time it will return 5

Then you can if it was called twice

```
assert test_mock.call_count == len(return_data)
```

return data should be Iterable (list, set, tuple) and can contain anything you would like (int, string, object, tuples, lists, ...)